# Recursing through a directory and converting music

Tags: bash, mp3, m4a

I'm writing a quick script to go through huge amounts of music to convert all the m4as to mp3s. Most of them are already mp3s, but I'd like all of them to be mp3s. Here's what I have so far:

```
for f in *.m4a; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320 "${f%.m4a}.mp3"; done
```

Does it on one level, how do I integrate this `ffmpeg` into a `find` command to do it recursively?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15930451/828193). To filter the filenames in the `find` command use the `-name '*.m4a'` option

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to also loop in subfolders, you can use the `globstar` shell optional behavior, see the [*Pattern Matching* section of the reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) and the [*Shopt Builtin* section of the reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) as so:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.m4a; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320 "${f%.m4a}.mp3"; done
```

Using `find` it's a bit trickier since you're using a [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). Here's a possibility that will be 100% safe regarding files with spaces or other funny symbols in their name:

```
find . -name '*.m4a' -type f -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320 "${0%.m4a}.mp3"' {} \;
```

This second possibility might be faster if you have a huge number of files, since [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) globbing is known to be quite slow for huge number of files.

---

In the `-exec` statement of `find`, I'm using `bash -c '...'`. In this case, every parameter given after the string to be executed will be set as the positional parameters, indexed from `0`, hence the `$0` that appears in the code

```
ffmpeg -i "$0" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320 "${0%.m4a}.mp3"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @OsmiumUSA It was the best choice! But hey, your question was well-posed, and you showed a little bit of research. It was not the "pleez give me teh codez" kind of question, so you deserved a good answer.